# I´m having a similar problem. Somehow my route doesnt seem to be working when i try to delete one post on my blog.It does nothing instead of delete it

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I can´t understand why it doesn´t delete one article when I push the button destroy on the show.html.erb file. If you can help...

i tried to see if it would even call the destroy function on the articles_controller.rb, and i think it doesn´t, don´t know why.

this is my routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root "articles#index"
  
  resources :articles
  # Define your application routes per the DSL in https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

  # Defines the root path route ("/")
  # root "articles#index"
end
```

articles_controller.rb

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @articles = Article.all
  end

  def show
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @article = Article.new(title: "...", body: "...")
  end

  def create
    @article = Article.new(article_params)

    if @article.save
      redirect_to @article
    else
      render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  def edit
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])

    if @article.update(article_params)
      redirect_to @article
    else
      render :edit, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    @article.destroy
    
    redirect_to root_path, status: :see_other
  end


  private
    def article_params
      params.require(:article).permit(:title, :body)
    end
end
```

show.html.erb

```
<h1><%= @article.title %></h1>

<p><%= @article.body %></p>

<ul>
  <li><%= link_to "Edit", edit_article_path(@article) %></li>
  <li><%= link_to "All Articles", root_path(@article) %></li>
  <li><%= link_to "Destroy", article_path(@article), data: {
                    turbo_method: :delete,
                    turbo_confirm: "Are you sure?"
                  } %></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: There are useful tools to help inspect the state of your routes.
You can run `rails routes --expanded` or visit `<your_site_root_address>/rails/info/routes`.

Can you add the output of one of those?

Comment: i dont have enough reputation to upload an image yet, and it is to big to ctrl copy. i will send it a soon as i can. Thanks

Comment: Can you simply copy/paste the relevant routes instead of the whole thing? Also see the edit to my answer below.

Comment: root_path GET / 
articles#index     

articles_path GET /articles(.:format) 
articles#index      

POST /articles(.:format) 
articles#create      

new_article_path GET /articles/new(.:format) 
articles#new      

edit_article_path GET /articles/:id/edit(.:format) 
articles#edit    

article_path GET /articles/:id(.:format) 
articles#show    
  
PATCH /articles/:id(.:format) 
articles#update   

PUT /articles/:id(.:format) 
articles#update     

DELETE /articles/:id(.:format) 
articles#destroy

Comment: Please edit your question to include the (formatted) routes in your latest comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn´t figure out what i was doing wrong still if i change the «link_to» to «button_to» it works perfectly. So if are having this problem might be good to change that

Answer (score 0):

From your comment above, these seem to be your routes:

```
root_path         GET    /                             articles#index
articles_path     GET    /articles(.:format)           articles#index
                  POST   /articles(.:format)           articles#create
new_article_path  GET    /articles/new(.:format)       articles#new
edit_article_path GET    /articles/:id/edit(.:format)  articles#edit
article_path      GET    /articles/:id(.:format)       articles#show
                  PATCH  /articles/:id(.:format)       articles#update
                  PUT    /articles/:id(.:format)       articles#update
                  DELETE /articles/:id(.:format)       articles#destroy
```

Right now your "Destory" button links to `article_path(@article)` with no `method`  so the default HTML verb is used, which is `GET`, which will navigate to your `show` action. You need to use the `DELETE` HTML verb instead.
That can be accomplished by adding the `method: :delete` attribute to your link like so:

```
<li>
  <%= link_to('Destroy',
              article_path(@article),
              method: :delete,
              data: {
                turbo_method: :delete,
                turbo_confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
</li>
```

Don't be confused by the turbo-link stuff. That is extra fluff that doesn't get the real job done on its own. You might be better off avoiding it until you're more comfortable with the situation.

Comment: thank you. Still it doesn´t delete. I will try to show my routes as it was asked